# Cannot login to Wordpress, running on localhost

Tags: wordpress, authentication, localhost

Instaling wordpress on localhost using WAMP server and PhpMyAdmin - MySql database. I created database, user to connect to database and wp-config file with all needed information. 
The problem occurs when, although instalation is completed without any problems, the login does not work. So I went to database and noticed that user (for admin panel) wasn't created.

Everytime I use wordpress on localhost, I have to manualy insert user into table. I have access to admin panel, but the some of the WP features are missing.
How can that happen, and why doesn't Wordpress create an user.

Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Some features are missing : yes, because by manually adding the user, you are disrupting referential integrity : it is ok for all features that fetch the user credentials here, but not for others (one good example is on a WP-MU site : you can add an administrator manually like this, but the administrator will not have access to the WPMU network features, only individual blog admin). 
So this is not the way to proceed.
Did you really launch the normal WordPress process at installation? You are right to create the database + user for database. But this user is not the same as the WordPress user, nothing to do with it. So then just create wp-config.php with the database user credentials and then launch the WordPress site by accessing the root URL (http://yoursite.com). WordPress asks you to create your blog, name, etc. + user. That is when the first user gets created.